# Any good philosophy debate recommendations?

Tags: reference-request, debate

[Note for admins - close if it doesn't fit the SE, I asked in the Symposium but no one answered so I came here. No need to downvote.]

Hi all, I saw Dennet, Krauss, and Massimo debate a couple of days ago (an absolutely bad debate in my honest opinion), and after that I thought why not looking at some more, so I came to the best place to ask for some recommendations.

So, first, I'd love to get any recommendations that has heavy philosophical talk, but specifically I'd like to see ones relating to science, religion, and all these relation to philosophy. Also I have no issue with reading correspondences instead, so that's welcomed too. Also debates *regarding* certain philosophers are welcomed too (e.g. a debate between two philosophers about some Heideggerian idea).

[Had no idea which tag to use but I saw there's a "debate" one so I used that.]

Comment: @Gordon thanks. Although, when I say "debate", I mean mainly live debates (videos/podcasts).

Comment: I understand now what you are aiming for,  so I thought it was best to remove those suggestions.

Comment: I once read a book from Umberto Eco: In cosa crede chi non crede? (with Carlo Maria Martini), 1996 - English translation: Belief or Nonbelief?: A Dialogue, 2000.

Answer (score 3):

There was a classic radio debate between Bertrand Russell and FC Copleston on the existence of God. I'm not sure if the full debate is online but here's about 20 minutes of it :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kz2GjKPbQds

The debate took place many years ago but Russell is always worth listening to.

Comment: Oh wow, Russell is awful in this debate. Expected more from him. Copleston did a very good job, although his argument is very old and very commonly refuted by atheists (often by the same way Russell did in the end). Anyway, you did provide me with a great YouTube channel :)

Comment: I agree : Copleston holds his ground very well. I suppose we have to make allowance for the fact that Russell was an old man, well past his prime, when the debate took place. But it is a famous debate and at least you know about it now.

Comment: Try these : Strawson being given a hard time by his ex-pupil Gareth Evans : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLV-eYacfbE  & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w__pIcl_1rs&t=62s. (Film quality poor at start.) Try also Quine against various adversaries : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPuCnu4X3Sw (1st of series of 9).